# Connection Error from C# and Works from SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection

While trying to connect to SQLServer from C# the error # reported is 4060 and I get...

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   HResult=0x80131904
> Message=Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login.
> The login failed. Login failed for user 'DBClient'.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider   StackTrace:

When using the credentials from SSMS, all is good.

1. Using SQL authentication.
2. The MSSQL database server is a different machine on the local network.
3. The C# code is on a dev machine and the error occurs when clicking the "IIS Express Google Chrome" button to view in a browser.  Here is the C# code...

> sqlConnect = new SqlConnection();
>
> sqlConnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source = SlaDAS; Initial Catalog =
> MyDatabase; Uid = DBClient; Pwd = 123456PW; Connection Timeout = 30;
> Max Pool Size = 500";
>
> sqlConnect.Open();

I have also tried a lot of different versions of the string and everything returns this error.

Thanks for all help, Stanley

Comment: Try Server=MachineName instead of Data Source in your connection string.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Changing "Data Source=SlaDAS" to "Server=SlaDAS" returns the same error.

Comment: What is the instance name of your sql server?  If it is localhost then try serverName\instanceName Have a read the link. For example if it is default(localhost) then SlaDas\.

Comment: Changing "Data Source" to "Server" AND changing "uid": tp "User ID" results in this same error.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DBClient'.

Comment: >> What is the instance name of your sql server?  It is the default instance named MSSQLSERVER.  The server is on a different box, but on same local network.

Comment: When adding comments here in SO, how do I insert a carriage return without closing the comment?

Comment: I believe your SSMS is also installed on the same server as SQL Server. How about if you install SSMS on the client and try to access the sql server instance? You clearly have a credential issue. When you try to access sql server instance from another server(client in your case)  you will need to also open firewalls etc. You can try to add the port numbers in your connection string. Or try to use IP address of the machine instead.

Comment: Is ``MyDatabase`` the correct name of your database? the error says your app can connect to sql but not able to read data from your database. maybe given database name is not correct or the user has not access to database

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer

Answer (score 1):

We can get Visual Studio to help you generate a working connection string:

- Add a new DataSet type object to your project
- Open it, right click anywhere and choose Add TableAdapter
- Go through the wizard, at some point you'll have to create a connection string. Click **Add Connection**:

[image]

- If the database type is wrong (mine has opened suggesting Access), click Change:

[image]

- Change it to SQL Server, and check it uses the SQLS driver, not the OLE one:

[image]

- You might see this, click OK if you do:

[image]

- And then fill in the rest of your details, the dialog should look mostly like SSMS; fill in the same details, click **Test Connection** or tweak some things etc til you get success..

[image]

- On the next page of the wizard, choose "SQL that retrieves rows", fill in some query, `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = @id` - it doesn't matter what table, especially if you aren't going to use this strongly typed dataset as your data access layer.. Just make it any valid query as a test
- Name it **FillById**
- Finish the wizard

**Now your settings file of your app contains a working connection string**

**You could use it from there, copy it etc if you're using EF, dapper or some other ORM, and throw the DataSet away** but if you're planning on using data adapters and datatables like this:

```
using(var da as new DataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = @x", "Data Source=...."){
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", 1234);
  var dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
  
  int age = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Age"]);
  ...

}
```

Honestly it's easier and better to just do a tableadapter like:

```
var ta = new PersonTableAdapter(); //it's like a data adapter
var dt = new PersonDataTable();    //it's a datatable with extra properties so no casting

ta.FillById(dt, 1234);             //load record with id 1234

int age = dt[0].Age;               //it's an int already, no convert etc like above
```

You can add more queries to the tableadapter by right clicking it and choosing Add Query, e.g. so you can add `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE @firstname` and call it FillByFirstNameLike then:

```
ta.FillByFirstNameLike(dt, "Jo%"); //find all person names starting with Jo
```

Or to return a datatable:

```
var dt = ta.GetDataByFirstNameLike("Jo%"); //get a new PersonDataTable
```

## TLDR

Use Visual Studio to help you create a working connection string using the wizards in a DataSet. As part of the process you'll have to get a working connection and you'll be able to easily prove it working and test downloading data/connection etc without tedious trial and error doing it in code. When you're done the correct connection string is in your settings/config and can just be used from there directly. You can discard the dataset, but if you're planning on using dataadapters and datatables to retrieve your data, it'll make life a lot easier to use the tableadapters and strongly typed datatables in the dataset instead

Comment: It is not related to question.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad yes, it is.. See the bit of the answer that I made bold. This is a way of getting a working connection string into a C# application, using a graphical interface that the user is familiar with because it is just like the one in SSMS